# How to get the client's network?

Tags: php

I did a lot of digging and still can't figure out how to get my visitors "network".

On Google analytics I can see this data easily (under audience > technology) but I would like to get it with PHP.

Can anyone share your experience on how to get this data?
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "network"? IP Address?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytic gives you a javascript code so everything that google analytics has is collected client side (browser version, screen size, etc...)

G/A detects client's ip address when browser loads the G/A given javascript code. after that google looks into the ip database and gives you possible location and network name

if you wanna do same in php use ip address and rich IP database

Comment: Ok, thanks - So, any idea how can I get the "hostname" of a user? I have webalizer on my server which shows "hostname" of users - how can I access this info per user?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about browser info, etc?

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Other [`$_SERVER` indices](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Also see [`get_browser`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)